# How to use Ruby's gsub function to replace excessive '\n' on a string

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, gsub

I have this string:

```
string = "SEGUNDA A SEXTA\n05:24 \n05:48\n06:12\n06:36\n07:00\n07:24\n07:48\n\n08:12 \n08:36\n09:00\n09:24\n09:48\n10:12\n10:36\n11:00 \n11:24\n11:48\n12:12\n12:36\n13:00\n13:24\n13:48 \n14:12\n14:36\n15:00\n15:24\n15:48\n16:12\n16:36 \n17:00\n17:24\n17:48\n18:12\n18:36\n19:00\n19:48 \n20:36\n21:24\n22:26\n23:15\n00:00\n"
```

And I'd like to replace all `\n\n` occurrences to only one `\n` and if it's possible I'd like to remove also all `" "` (spaces) between the numbers and the newline character `\n`

I'm trying to do:

```
string.gsub(/\n\n/, '\n')
```

but it is replacing `\n\n` by `\\n`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just replace your single quotes with double quotes.  And you can make it more concise as such:  `string.gsub(/\n{2}/, "\n")`.

Comment: And to remove the SPACES between the numbers?

Comment: I'm afraid to answer with this but how about: `string.gsub(/(?<=\d)\s\n/, "")`?

Comment: @squiguy - That's technically one char less concise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
string.gsub( / *\n+/, "\n" )
```

This searches for zero or more spaces followed by one or more newlines, and replaces the match with a single newline.

Answer (score 7):

The real reason is because single quoted sting doesn't escape special characters (like \n).

`string.gsub(/\n/, '\n')`

It replaces one single character \n with two characters '\' and 'n'

You can see the difference by printing the string:

```
[302] pry(main)> puts '\n'
\n
=> nil

[303] pry(main)> puts "\n"

=> nil

[304] pry(main)> string = '\n'
=> "\\n"
[305] pry(main)> string = "\n"
=> "\n"
```

Comment: "single quoted sting doesn't escape special characters" is untrue, it escapes everything. As result '\n' is equivalent to "\\n".